# Why we can use Predicate parameter without importing it?

Tags: java, import, java-8, predicate

Usually, when we use Predicate, we need to import java.util.function.Predicate. But in my case, if we use Predicate as a parameter in a method (removeIf()), we don't need to import Predicate. Why is that?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("ABCDEFG"); 
        list.add("ABC");
        list.removeIf(s -> s.length() > 4);
        System.out.println(list);   // ABC
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if we use Predicate as a parameter in a method (removeIf()), we don't
>   need to import Predicate. Why is that?

Since `Predicate` is a `FunctionalInterface` that can be represented as a lambda without the use of any `import`s. The type of the lambda is inferred by the compiler.

Comment: But if we don't import it, how do Java knows that Predicate is even an interface?

Comment: @AnhMinhTran The compiler infers it for you. Of course, based on the context, you've used the lambda in.

Comment: Found one of the [FAQ link](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-is-the-type-of-a-lambda-expression/) around lambda for this. Might be helpful for further interests.